# C++ promise/future: Which to return from a function?

Tags: c++, c++11, promise, future

I have a function that returns a reference to a std::promise:

```
std::shared_ptr<std::promise<void>> play();
```

(More info: The function plays media on some device, and the return value represents when this playing is complete. If play is called a second time, a value is set on the promise returned the first time, and a new promise is created and returned for this second call)

The caller can then catch the value and wait on the future:

```
auto this_future = play()->get_future();
this_future.wait();
```

Does it make sense to return a reference to the promise, or should I return the future instead, so that the calling function does not have to call get_future()?

Comment: Having a std::promise/std::future in a std::shared_ptr might be questionable (It breaks the no copy concept of std::promise/std::future)

Comment: Agreed; the shared_ptr was actually needed to get around these no-copy issues, as I wanted to store them in a collection and return them from a function. However, I can't see where this would cause issues.

Comment: @ScottM: You can also `std::move` futures if you want to store then in a collection, say `std::vector<std::future<T>>`.

Comment: You read my mind! I've been sitting here trying to figure out if I could modify the second function `playAll()` to return `std::vector<std::future<void>>` instead of the corresponding collection of promise refereneces.

Comment: The no-copy premise of `std::future` means that only ONE consumer should ever have it and think they have the right to `.get()` from it.  With a `std::shared_ptr<std::future<X>>`, you are saying "more than one client has equal ownership of this `future`".  This is code smell.  Similarly, `std::promise<X>` is supposed to be uniquely owned by the producer of the data: having two pieces of code with shared ownership implies both have the right to set its value (or read its future).  `play()` should return `std::future<void>`.  Internally a `std::promise<void> old_promise` can be kept around.

Comment: OK, so I could run into issues returning a shared_ptr<promise<T>> because the caller can potentially call get_future() on it multiple times, or call set_value(). That makes sense.

Comment: Using technical words correctly is important.  You say: "I have a function that returns a reference to a std::promise" but you show a function that returns by value a shared_ptr to the std::promise. If you don't understand the difference, learn it.  If you do understand the difference, be more careful with your words and concepts, please.  Pedants are  better programmers.

Comment: My apologies - I was purposely using reference loosely as "an object that refers to a std::promise object" because I didn't want to get caught up in the debate of "what kind of reference" (promise&, promise*, or some sort of smart ptr) - I wanted to focus on whether to expose a std::future object or (some sort of) reference to a std::promise.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since the implementation of `play()` is *not* posted, I'd say most likely you should return the future, and the function should work with the promise itself, most likely in a different thread. The rationale for this design stems from the fact that promise is a producer end, and future is a consumer end — so the function would produce a value, set it through the promise instance, which will notify the future that result has arrived through `get`.

However, note that, you don't have to return a `std::shared_ptr<std::future<T>>` — just `std::future<T>` would work great.